# Checking services logs for "working time" users -- conditions in having clause

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a table of service usage by user id that is accompanied by a dimension table including date, day of the week, hour of the day, etc. Each time the user uses the service, a new row is created that logs the time of use.

I want to find users that use the service at least four out of five weekdays, each day logging usage in at least 8 separate hours of the day. These are the "working time" users. How can I best achieve this?

Currently, I am compromising with the `having` clause below, which does not capture the conditions specified above completely. Rather, it gets the users that use the service for at least 16 weekdays in a month with an *average* usage of at least 8 hours a day.

```
select 
a.userId
from SERVICE_LOGS_MTHLY a 
inner join DIM_TIME_OF_DAY b
  on a.TOD_ID = b.TOD_ID
having
  count(distinct (case when b.day_of_week in ('MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY') then a.day end)) >= 16 
  AND
  count(distinct (case when b.day_of_week in ('MONDAY') then a.day||b.hour24 end)) >= 8*count(distinct (case when b.day_of_week in ('MONDAY') then a.day end))
  AND
  count(distinct (case when b.day_of_week in ('TUESDAY') then a.day||b.hour24 end)) >= 8*count(distinct (case when b.day_of_week in ('TUESDAY') then a.day end))
  AND
  count(distinct (case when b.day_of_week in ('WEDNESDAY') then a.day||b.hour24 end)) >= 8*count(distinct (case when b.day_of_week in ('WEDNESDAY') then a.day end))
  AND
  count(distinct (case when b.day_of_week in ('THURSDAY') then a.day||b.hour24 end)) >= 8*count(distinct (case when b.day_of_week in ('THURSDAY') then a.day end))
  AND
  count(distinct (case when b.day_of_week in ('FRIDAY') then a.day||b.hour24 end)) >= 8*count(distinct (case when b.day_of_week in ('FRIDAY') then a.day end))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This involves aggregating an aggregate, that is, it involves two steps. One is to provide how many hours each day a user logs the service and the other to provide the number of weekdays each week.

Using a simple table named Hourly which seems to match minimally the description of your table, see my <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60733/4/0)</kbd> scenario.

The first step is to aggregate hours daily.

```
select  h.ID, h.StartDate, count(*) as DailyCount
from    Hourly  h
where   DoW in( 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday' )
group by h.ID, h.StartDate;
```

You weren't too clear so this assumes one entry for an hour of use no matter how many times in that hour the user performs a loggable event. Adjust if necessary.

Now just add up for each week how many 8 or greater days. This uses the results of the query above so make that into a CTE or create a view from it if you don't have CTEs available (MySQL).

```
with
Daily( ID, StartDate, DailyCount )as(
    select  h.ID, h.StartDate, count(*) as DailyCount
    from    Hourly  h
    where   DoW in( 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday' )
    group by h.ID, h.StartDate
)
select  d.ID, Sum( case when DailyCount < 8 then 0 else 1 end ) as WeeklyCount
from    Daily   d
group by d.ID, To_Char( d.StartDate, 'iw' );
```

Now you just check for a WeeklyCount of 4 or more for each user for each week.

Note: the `To_Char` allows you to group by week. For most DBMSs other than Oracle, this is provided by a `DatePart` function.